# MIPS - loading individual bits

Tags: mips, declaration, bit

Fellow SO users,

If I have a value, say 1010 saved in memory, how do I load each of the bits starting from the MSB to the LSB one at a time? By this I mean,

```
while loop
    load $t1 with 1
    shift some number by the amount indicated by the value in $t1 (1)
    load $t1 with 0
    shift some number by the amount indicated by the value in $t1 (0)
    do the same until you load the LSB which is 0
    start again at MSB (rotate right?)
end loop
```

I need some tips on how to declare this value in memory in the `.data` segment first. Do I declare this as:

```
value: .byte 00001010
```

And how do I load the individual bits into registers?

Kind regards

Comment: The way you write binary immediates depends on the assembler. It's possible that the assembler supports e.g. a `b` suffix (`00001010b`), or it might not. You could always write the same number in hex (`0Ah` / `0x0A`) or decimal (10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `SLT` instruction described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#Logical). Here is some pseudocode:

```
lbu $s0, value     # load the byte
sll $s0, $s0, 24   # shift it into the upper byte of $s0
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  # $t0 is set to 1 if the sign bit (i.e. bit 31) of $s0 is set
  slt  $t0, $s0, $zero   
  # $t0 now holds the value of the ith bit of value
  . . . .          # do something with $t0
  sll $s0, $s0, 1  # shift on to the next bit
}
```

Implementing the `for` loop in assembler is left as an exercise for the reader.